# Which command and alias for pip3.7

Tags: python3, versions, pip, alias

I created the following alias to run `pip3.7` everytime I use `pip` command:

```
pip='pip3.7'
```

Now, bash says:

```
pip -V pip 18.1 from /home/uname/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

but, the command `which pip` says:

```
which pip /home/uname/.local/bin/pip
```

while the executables for pip3.7 seem to be located at different folders:

```
whereis pip3.7: /usr/local/bin/pip3.7 /home/uname/.local/bin/pip3.7 /home/uname/.local/bin/pip3
```

I think maybe that in `which pip`, the world `pip` is not seen as the command actually triggered by the alias, thus it returns the pip path like if alias would not exist. This confuses me on which version actually runs with `pip` command.

Comment: `type -a pip` will show you which one `bash` runs. `type -a pip3.7` will show you which one your alias runs.

Comment: I think this will answer your question: [Why not use “which”? What to use then? - Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249/117037)

Comment: @waltinator But does alias override bash?  
`type -a pip - pip is aliased to "pip3.7"`  
`pip is /home/uname/.local/bin/pip`.  And then: 
`type -a pip3.7 - pip3.7 is /home/uname/.local/bin/pip3.7`
`pip3.7 is /usr/local/bin/pip3.7`

Answer (score 1):

`which` can only find executables in the PATH.

`type` is a Bash builtin, and will show aliases, plus other Bash-internal commands like functions, keywords, and builtins, plus executables and hashed executables.

Example shell session:

```
$ pip -V
pip 8.1.2 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
$ alias pip=pip3
$ type pip
pip is aliased to `pip3'
$ type pip3
pip3 is /usr/local/bin/pip3
$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
$ pip -V
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (python 3.4)
$ type pip3
pip3 is hashed (/usr/local/bin/pip3)
```

Comment: I have the same situation as the example, except that also deleting the alias I have the following: `pip -V pip 18.1 from /home/g-luca/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)`

Answer (score 0):

It depends what python interpreter you want to use. You can install same python and pip several times on one machine.

If you want to use standard python like

```
apt install python3
apt install python3-pip
```

then you can set alias as

```
alias pip='/usr/bin/pip3'
```

If you want to use a different installation of python I recommend using python virtual environment. You can install it with

```
apt-get install python3-venv
```

You can also find several tutorials in internet on how to use python virtual environment.